# How to open a gif without loop repetition with oeg

Tags: images, imagemagick, gif, animation

I use to open `.gif` file with

```
 eog -f myfile.gif
```

The gif animation is however running in loop.

What I want is to display the animation once and then quit.

How to avoid this?

Please also help in case you would have any better utility to  open `.gif`,

Comment: It loops forever as that's how your `gif` was animated... If you unpack it with e.g. `convert myfile.gif frames%02d.gif` and then recreate another animated gif with `convert -delay 30 frames*.gif -loop 1 loop_once.gif` and run `eog loop_once.gif` it will "play" the animation only once